# MATLAB: locate the first position of each unique number from a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, element, unique

I wish to locate the first position of each unique number from a vector but without a for loop:

e.g

```
a=[1 1 2 2 3 4 2 1 3 4];
```

and I can obtain the unique number by having:

```
uniq=unique(a);
```

where uniq = [1 2 3 4]

What I want is to obtain each number's first appearance location, any ideas????

```
first_pos = [1 3 5 6]
```

where 1 is firstly appear in position 1, 4 is firstly appear in the sixth position from the vector

ALSO, what about the position of the second appearance??

```
second_pos = [2 4 9 10]
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the second output of `unique`, and use the `'first'` option:

```
>> A = [1 1 2 2 3 4 2 1 3 4];
>> [a,b] = unique(A, 'first')
a =
    1     2     3     4  %// the unique values
b =
    1     3     5     6  %// the first indices where these values occur
```

To find the locations of the second occurrences,

```
%// replace first occurrences with some random number
R = rand;

%// and do the same as before
A(b) = R;
[a2,b2] = unique(A, 'first');

%// Our random number is NOT part of original vector
b2(a2==R)=[];
a2(a2==R)=[];
```

with this:

```
b2 =
    2     4     9    10
```

Note that there will have to be at least 2 occurrences of each number in the vector `A` if the sizes of `b` and `b2` are to agree (this was not the case before your edit).

Comment: but what about the position of the second appearance?

Comment: @FF0605 If there are exactly two apperances of each number, the second can of course also be found by locating the last element: `[~,b] = unique(A)`

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Thanks, simple and nice try, there is a little typo in your post of "A = [1 1 2 2 3 4 2 1]" should be replaced by "a=[1 1 2 2 3 4 2 1 3 4]"

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Thanks, isn't the comment should be [~,b] = unique(A,'last') ?

Comment: @FF0605: well, that's how you first posted it :) I'll correct it, thanks.

Comment: @FF0605 Last is in fact the default setting, so it can be left out. But if it is important that you always have the last, you could consider adding the string anyway to ensure it will behave in future Matlab versions. Also this would perhaps make the code more comprehensible.